# Running angular from node.js server

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express

I have following files -

1) index.html

2) app.js (angular controllers here)

3) routes.js (I'm trying to load index.html from here - listening on localhost :3000)

4) index.css

5) node_modules folder

**routes.js :**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.use("/node_modules", express.static('node_modules'));        
app.use("/public", express.static('public'));

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

When I open **index.html** file normally by clicking on it from file explorer, it opens fine as expected.

[image]

But, when I run routes.js, to fetch the same **index.html** file, I get the raw HTML without angular effects. **Why is this?**

[image]

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

I can now access my index.css and app.js from `localhost:3000/public/`.
I used `app.use("/public", express.static('public'));` in my `routes.js`.

But now I can only get `css` included in my page, but still looks like angular is not included. I couldn't see the tabs. Please look at above screenshot of `index.html` file with tabs.

**How can I include angular? Isn't it included from the HTML itself?**

[image]

**index.html -**

```
<html>
...
...
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="public/index.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

<body>
...
...

<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="public/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="public/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :** **I solved it by including**

```
app.use("/node_modules", express.static('node_modules'));
```

in my routes.js file. So now express also uses that folder, so `angular` files in that folder are used to serve my index.html file.
Now, running my `localhost:3000/` gives me the expected result. Thanks!

Comment: node_modules are the folder where nodejs keeps its modules, angular.js is a web application framework it should not be placed in node_modules in any way, the same for the socker.io client library, you should take it out of node_modules. Also regrading public in other links, the route is not the same as the folder on a disk in my example you should place your files in public/javascript folder on disk, but access them as <script src="/js/app.js">

Comment: @teamnorge Thanks for your reply. I can now access my js and css files. But angular doesn't seem to work. Please look at my edited question. I am using and referring to a local copy of angularJS which I downloaded instead of linking to a CDN url. Is that wrong? Correct me!

Comment: no problem having your local copy of angularjs, just put it into proper directory (somewhere within public/javascript), as I mentioned above node_modules is not the proper place to keep it.

Comment: I solved it @teamnorge. Just going by the same logic for serving static files in express. I also included it to serve my 'node_modules' by app.use("/node_modules", express.static('node_modules')); Now, the page is using angular. Thanks 'teamnorge' for sticking with my question. I'll be happy to accept your answer, please include this in your answer - app.use("/node_modules", express.static('node_modules'));.

Comment: Sorry, I won't include it, because I do not recommend having a route into node_modules folder, better take your web related libraries out of it and place in another folder being also set as static in expressjs.

Comment: @teamnorge No problem. But as a beginner I can only know that it sounds as a best practice, but I see no harm in including it. If you can provide a reason for your recommendation it will help me and other beginners. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your static files (js/css) are not accessible through `expressjs`, you can check in a browser console if it's 404?

By the way did you add the directory where `app.js` stored as static in `expressjs` or is it located in the same directory as `index.html`?

Something like:

```
app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/javascripts')));
```

Alternatively you can add a route to your `app.js`:

```
app.get('/js/app.js', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app.js');
});
```

but it's not recommended, just for the tests.

Comment: app.js is in the same directory as index.html. I'm trying to include js and css files as you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I  coudn't load those files from express and adding app.js also didn't work.

Comment: app.js has controllers with empty body. So, adding them or not should not make much difference. I linked css and js files in my HTML, so I think that mustn't be an issue. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So, do you see css files then? Just to be simple, you can make one folder - public, put everything there and specify app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); then all your static files must be accessible from /

Comment: I did just as you suggested. Looks like I can't access my public folder as well. Any help? I still get the same HTML page without CSS and angular.

Comment: Thanks! I additionally also included my node_modules folder by using app.use("/node_modules", express.static('node_modules')); So, the angular files are now used.

Answer (score 1):

You are  running your node sever.

So, you have mention the path for your static files like js,css.

Define the path for your **app.js** which include your controller.

Assume your `app.js` is in public folder within root directory,

then define like this in your `route.js`

**app.use(express.static('public'));**

Comment: As suggested by@teamnorge.. I used app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); to include my files in /public folder, but to no avail. I also couldn't access my public folder from local host. Please look at my edited question.

Comment: Please show me your index.html file where you include you script.

Comment: Please look at my edit. I included the snippet where I linked those files.